# umask for www-data user running PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: php, file-permissions, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, umask

Setting up a new webserver in Ubuntu 14.04 and trying to wrangle file permissions for PHP generated files.

By default, all the directories and files in `/var/www` are owned/grouped to www-admin. Directory permissions are `rwxrwsr-x` and file permissions are `rw-rw-r--`.

We then set the group on a limited number of directories to www-data - this is so that PHP (via Apache) can write log and cache files in this location.

However, I cannot get PHP to obey a umask of `0002`, and so files generated by PHP are only writeable to the www-data user. This is a problem, since we use continuous integration, and some other cleanup processes.

So far, I have:

- Set the umask to 0002 in `/etc/pam.d/common-session`
- Set the umask to 0002 in `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive`
- Set the umask to 0002 in `/etc/profile`
- Set the umask to 0002 in `/etc/apache2/envvars`
- Set the umask to 0002 in `/etc/login.defs`
- Set the umask to 0002 for `www-data` in `/etc/passwd` using `sudo chfn -o "umask=002" daemon_username`

And I'm still stuck.

I've stopped/started the service, and even restarted the computer - no joy.

Answer (score 6):

"umask 002" in /etc/apache2/envvars should work.

Take notice that Apache must be restarted by "service apache2 stop; service apache2 start" for taking effect, not by "service apache2 restart"!

See here if you need an more detailed sample: https://serverfault.com/a/384922/228027

Comment: Given the Ubuntu 14.04 /etc/init.d/apache2, how does "service apache2 stop; service apache2 start" differ from "service apache2 restart"?

Comment: do_start in restart may be skipped depending on do_stop result.

Comment: Yeah, except in those situation you get an error and an exit. Hence, I really see no scenario where "service apache2 restart" can succeed, while still surprise you with the change not taking effect.

Comment: Well, all of those changes "should" work according to the sources I got them from - I'm asking the question because it didn't - and I pretty much always do a complete stop and start instead of restart these days.

Comment: @andol - i've had restarts silently fail with some mis-configurations (particularly SSL stuff that don't get picked up with a configtest).

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you run multiple sites you can set default group permission using Access Control Lists (ACL) per directory like so:

Set `setid` flag to force all new files to inherit group from directory:

```
root@sh1:/srv/www/php/fastwarren.ca# chmod g+s wordpress
```

Make new files have `rw` for the group permissions, ex. so that  `www-data` can write to files SFTPed by the upload user:

```
root@sh1:/srv/www/php/fastwarren.ca# setfacl --default --modify group:rwx wordpress
```

Confirm the ACL is like so:

```
root@sh1:/srv/www/php/fastwarren.ca# getfacl wordpress
# file: wordpress
# owner: carissacosgrove
# group: www-data
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Create a file to confirm it worked:

```
root@sh1:/srv/www/php/fastwarren.ca# ll test
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root www-data 0 Feb 17 01:09 test
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the files are being created by PHP-FPM. It's the parent process -- not apache2. The only way I could fix this is by adding the umask to /etc/init/php7.1-fpm.conf. Then restart PHP-FPM.

Related thread: [Nginx/php-fpm umask setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584021/nginx-php-fpm-umask-setting/21318057#21318057).

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't working for me either untill I realized the following: PDO SQLite driver plugin for Wordpress will create the database file with group read permission only.

Test you sanity by using the create script from here: [How do I set default umask in Apache on Debian?](https://serverfault.com/questions/383734/how-do-i-set-default-umask-in-apache-on-debian).