# Set umask 0002 for apache user: www-data

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, umask, www-data

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and would like to have apaches www-data user to create files that are writable by all users within that same group www-data.

So far I've tried to add

`umask 0002` or `umask 002`

to `/etc/apache2/envvar` but didn't have any success even after stopping and starting the apache service.

What else could I try?

I followed some other great tipps in other posts but weren't successful in creating writable files with www-data.

- [How do I set default umask...](https://serverfault.com/questions/383734/how-do-i-set-default-umask-in-apache-on-debian)
- [umask for www-data user running php on ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/624866/umask-for-www-data-user-running-php-on-ubuntu)

Thank you very much for your help :-)

Comment: How you (the webserver) are writing the files? Through a scripting language? Which? What are the actual file permissions of these new files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried put the umask command in /home/www-data/.bash_profile file?