# Can't create files with `ubuntu` user under `/var/www`

Tags: permissions, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04, www-data

I've added `ubuntu` user to the `www-data` group and set the folder permissions as follows:

```
sudo gpasswd -a "$USER" www-data
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0640 {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2750 {} \;
```

I can verify that `ubuntu` has been added to the group (running `groups` shows `ubuntu www-data`). I can access and read any files and directories in the /var/www directory as `ubuntu`.

I want to grant *write* permissions to `ubuntu` user in certain directories. Running `sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/public/uploads/` gives `ubuntu` access to write into this folder.

The problem is that when `www-data` creates new directories in `/var/www/public/uploads/`, `ubuntu` does not have permission to write in these newly created directories.

That is, when `www-data` creates `/var/www/public/uploads/some-new-folder/`, `ubuntu` cannot touch files in `some-new-folder`.

How can I change the permissions so that any files and directories created by `www-data` in specific paths will be writable by `ubuntu` as well?

Comment: This may help: http://serverfault.com/questions/383734/how-do-i-set-default-umask-in-apache-on-debian

Comment: I tried setting `umask` to 002 in `/etc/apache2/envvars`, restarted Apache, also searched for other solutions involving setting the umask. Nothing worked so far, `www-data` user keeps creating new directories with `drwxr-sr-x` permissions instead of `drwxrwsr-x`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "setgid" bit of the parent folder ("uploads", in this case) and any file created within it will have the specified group membership regardless of the creator. The command is below. Here is a good post I found on "setgid": http://www.toptip.ca/2010/03/linux-setgid-on-directory.html

Setgid with chmod: sudo chmod g+s /var/www/public/uploads/ <*your group*>

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works to change existing directories to be writable, but any new directories created by `www-data` user are still not writable by `ubuntu`. New folders have `drwxr-sr-x` permissions. So even though the shared group ID is present, group users still cannot write to this path.